# Having trouble with facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

Good day All,
I am having trouble with facebook login app it works great even for login but somehow it stores wrong id for particular users. the test site is at lahebe.com
I am particularly not having trouble with or may be coz am admin here is my code.
What can I do?? 
`$_SESSION['user_profile'] = $user_profile;`
thats how am setting the session it works marvelous for me but not othe users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you store it in a database? If yes I have had such a problem when the data type was incorrect. Try changing the data type to varchar(100)

Comment: ok let me try. But storing data in the data gives me the right id. But a link to profile: 
$facebook_id=$lahebe['id']; <a href='profile_page.php?user=$facebook_id' class='link_2'>$name </a>, please try and login after login click home then you name you should see the id in the url  is not correct